# Atlas PH Sensor Query Failed

Tags: i2c, sensor

Hi I have bought Atlas PH Probe and followed the instructions to use the EZO PH circuit in i2c. The board lights up in blue color. When i use i2cdetect -y 1 i am getting default port 63 in the display.
I changed the port to 63 in the script even then i am not even able to get any data when i give the command I.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and looked through the i2c.py code and found the `default_address` variable was set to 98. I changed this to 99 and it worked ok after that.